# java parsing string with variable number of fields

Tags: java, parsing

I understand that there are lot of question about parsing in Java.
However I am unable to figure out how to exactly parse the following string -

The Input String is as -

`[[0, 0] -> 0, [0, 1] -> 1, [0, 2] -> 2, [1, 0] -> 3, [0, 4] -> 1, [0, 1] -> 2, [0, 6] -> 3, else -> 2`

i would like the output to be parsed this as -

```
Entry 1 : number1, number2, number3
Entry 2 : number4, number5, number6
...
```

so for this example the output would be -

```
Entry 1 : 0, 0, 0
Entry 2 : 0, 1, 1
....
```

To be precise the `else -> 2` part should be ignored.

Now my question is that -

- One entry contains something else than that of the pattern
- The amount of numbers between the square bracket can vary. 
  for example the input string can be as - `[[0] -> 0, [1] -> 1, [2] -> 2, else -> 2`

What I tried was using split for the second example which I showed -

```
String value = "[[0] -> 0, [1] -> 1, [2] -> 2, else -> 2";
value = value.replaceAll("\\[", "");
value = value.replaceAll("\\]", "");
String split[] = value.split(",");

for(int j=0;j<split.length;j++)
{
    String split2[] = split[j].split("->");
    split2[0] = split2[0].replaceAll("\\s","");
    if(split2[0].contains("else"))
        continue;    
    System.out.println(split2[0],+ " " + split split2[1].replaceAll("\\s",""));                     
}
```

But this won't work for variable amount of numbers in square brackets.
How exactly should I do the pattern matching? Can I use Regex?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't get your question. What exactly are you hoping to parse from the string?

Comment: What does [0, 6] -> 3, else -> 2 mean?  What's the output look like?

Comment: i just ignore the else part. its an output produced by a third party tool.

Comment: What does this string represent, exactly? If it's data of some kind, then use JSON or XML to serialize it.

Comment: it is just a model which is output in a string format.

Comment: Be more specific, please.

Comment: to be specific, the string represents the values of an array. now the array can be of any dimensions. when it is 2 dimensions it will be like this `[0,0] -> 0` which means that element `arr[0][0]=0`.

Comment: There's nothing here that can't be represented in JSON or XML. Use a more standard format to serialize your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for the next `->`, then split at the next `,` after that to get one "segment". Now, split that segment at the `->` to get the "key" and "value" parts. Finally, split the key at the remaining `,`s to separate the keys (if it is not the final "else"-segment).

```
String value = "[[0, 0] -> 0, [0, 1] -> 1, [0, 2] -> 2, [1, 0] -> 3, [0, 4] -> 1, [0, 1] -> 2, [0, 6] -> 3, else -> 2";
value = value.replaceAll("\\[", "");
value = value.replaceAll("\\]", "");
value = value.replaceAll(" ", "");               // remove spaces, too,
                                                 // no need to trim later
int start = 0;
while (start < value.length()) {
    int arrow = value.indexOf("->", start);      // next -> after start
    int comma = value.indexOf(",", arrow);       // next comma after ->
    comma = comma > -1 ? comma : value.length(); // final segment?

    String segment = value.substring(start, comma);
    String key = segment.split("->")[0];         // before ->
    String val = segment.split("->")[1];         // after ->

    if (key.contains("else")) {
        System.out.println("Default: " + val);
    } else {
        String[] keys = key.split(",");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(keys) + ": " + val);
    }
    start = comma + 1;                           // continue after segment
}
```

(Output does not completely match your updated question, but this should be easy to fix.)

---

You can use Regular Expressions, too, using a pattern like `\[\d+(, \d+)*\] -> \d+`. This will not match the `else` part, but I understand that that's not important anyway.

```
String regex = "(\\[\\d+(, \\d+)*\\] -> \\d+)";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(value);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

The output of `matcher.group()` will be Strings like `"[0, 0] -> 0"`.

Comment: thanks is exactly i was trying to find out. however i could not come with the perfect logic. I wa thinking, maybe I need `regex`, which I don't have any experience with. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Pay attemtion to the format of your input; look for patterns.  the start of a brackeded number range starts with '['.  the end of a brackedted number range ends with ']'  after the range is an arrow "->", a number, and a comma.  take a look at the output of the code below and your solution should be easy to reach:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final String input = "[[3] -> 7, [0, 0] -> 0, [0, 1] -> 1, [0, 2] -> 2, [1, 0] -> 3, [0, 4] -> 1, [0, 1] -> 2, [0, 6] -> 3, else -> 2";
        String[] split;

        split = StringUtils.split(input, "->, ");

        for (String item : split)
        {
            System.out.println("Item: " + item);
        }
    }
```

Note: StringUtils is part of [apache commons lang.](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)

Comment: Given your input, the split wouldn't return anything.

Comment: I misunderstood the method `StringUtils.split` I thought it would split on the string "->, " Instead it is spiting on the chars: `"-"` `">"` `","` `" "`